# Concatenate a list until a certain character

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, concatenation

I have this list:

```
Jokes =   ['First joke', 'Still first', '', 'Second Joke', 'Still second joke', 'Still 2nd joke']
```

I would want to concatenate the list as follow:

```
Jokes = ['First joke \n Still first', 'Second joke \n Still second joke \n Still 2nd joke']
```

Is this somehow possible?

Thank you,

Comment: "Is this somehow possible?" - yes, it is. What code have you written to solve this and where exactly are you facing issues?

Comment: I know you have your answer, but I'm still curios: is the empty item separating the 'first joke' chain from the 'second joke' chain actually acting as a separator or is it there randomly?

Comment: @JackFleeting ; It's not random , 'None' is actually a delimitor ; context: I had a text with lot of jokes in in it and they are separated by a new line between them. I wrote this  'jokes = f.read().strip().split("\n")' and it generated the list like ['First joke', 'Still first', '', 'Second Joke', 'Still second joke', 'Still 2nd joke', '', '3rd joke', 'is the', 'best', '', '4th joke'] . Hope this clarifies :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example solution:

```
jokes = ['First joke', 'Still first', '', 'Second Joke', 'Still second joke', 'Still 2nd joke']

groups = [[]]
for part in jokes:
    if part:
        groups[-1].append(part)
    else:
        groups.append([])

result = [' \n '.join(joke) for joke in groups]
print(result)
```

Comment: @FabioFarago I'm always glad to help :)

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
jokes = ['First joke', 'Still first', '', 'Second Joke', 'Still second joke', 'Still 2nd joke']
jokes2 = []
for i in range(len(jokes) // 2):
    jokes2.append(jokes[2 * i] + ' \n ' + jokes[2 * i + 1])
print(jokes2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: I got `['First joke \n Still first', ' \n Second Joke', 'Still second joke \n Still 2nd joke']` instead of `['First joke \n Still first', 'Second joke \n Still second joke \n Still 2nd joke']`

Answer (score 0):

What criteria are you using to determine when to split. Are you using the ''? Are you expecting exactly the phrase "first joke" "second joke"? You don't tell us your criteria, so we are guessing. Suppose it is the ''.

```
Jokes = ['First joke', 'Still first', '', 'Second Joke', 'Still second joke', 'Still 2nd joke']
idx   = Jokes.index('')
Jokes = ['\n'.join(Jokes[:idx]),'\n'.join(Jokes[idx+1:])]
print(Jokes)
```

If you have a longer list or more than one '', then this answer obviously changes. But I have no details, so I don't know.